# ajaxで関数を呼び出したいのですがエラーが出ます。

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

現在VisualStudio2019 WebFormsでプログラムを製作中です。

現状、「ボタンをクリックした際に、ajaxで中身のない関数に飛ぶ」というだけの処理内容になっているのですが、クリックした際にエラーが出ます。
以下がそのエラー内容になります。

「コントラクト名 'ShopSupply.Service2' は、サービス 'Service2' によって実装されたコントラクトの一覧から見つかりませんでした。」

ネットで調べてみたところ、WebConfigの中のendpointのcontractの値を変えれば解決する、というようなことが書かれていましたが、様々な書き方を試しても上手くいきません。

以下がWebConfigの一部抜粋になります。
よろしくお願いします。

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ShopSupply.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>

        <serviceBehaviors>

            <behavior name="ajaxServiceBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>

            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service name="ShopSupply.Service2">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ShopSupply.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ShopSupply.Service2" />
        </service>

    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


</system.serviceModel>
```

【追記】
自己解決しました。
そもそもWCFがインストールされていなかったのが原因だったようです。

Comment: Ajax から呼び出すサーバー側は何ですか？ Web Service? WCF? その他？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

サーバー側は WCF のようですので、その場合のサンプルを紹介します。

WCF と jQuery AJAX
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2015/10/15/wcf-and-jquery-ajax.aspx

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
WCF、AJAXをヒントにサンプルサイトを探してみました。
追記しましたのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「Service2.svc.vbに以下の2行が抜けている」とかそいうレベルの問題ではなくて、全くできてないのではないかと思いますけど。紹介したサイトの通りやってみてください。もしくは WCF はやめて、もっと簡単な Web Service を使うように方針転換するとか。

Comment: わかりました。１からやり直してみようと思います。ありがとうございます。